# How to create a constructor of linked list for iterator class in c++?

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

When I try to run this code I get this error :

> constructor for 'Linkedlist' must explicitly initialize the member
> 'point' which does not have a default constructor
> Linkedlist::Linkedlist()

```
class Node {
    public:
        Node* next;
        Node* prev;
        Elem elem;
        friend class Linkedlist;
        Node(): next(NULL), prev(NULL)
        {}
        Node(Elem elem) : elem(elem)
        {}
};

class Iterator {
private:
    Node* iter;
    //Iterator(Node curr);
public:
    friend class Linkedlist; 
    Iterator(Node* curr) {
        iter=curr;
    } 
};

class Linkedlist { 
private:
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;
    int N;
    Iterator point;
public:
    Iterator point;
    Linkedlist();
};

Linkedlist::Linkedlist() {
    N = 0;
    head = new Node();
    tail  = new Node();
    head->next = tail;
    tail->prev = head;
    point.iter = head;
}
```

I am not sure how to solve this problem, any help appreciated!

Comment: Your `Iterator` class should maintain a `Node* currentNode;` member variable, not a `Node iter;`.

Comment: actually there is * but somehow it did not appeared, so I edited

Comment: `iter` still is a confusing name, also the whole `Iterator` class definition should be a nested class of `LinkedList`.

Comment: Your constructor for LinkedList doesn't construct Iterator point, so the compiler tries to construct it using the default constructor, which doesn't exist. Either add one, or initialize it explicitly.

Comment: You need to add call to point constructor inside linkedlist constructor

Comment: Unrelated: `head = new Node();` places a bogus node in your list. So does `tail  = new Node();`, but likely the `tail` node will merely be leaked. It's usually better if you think of `head` as being a specialized case of a next pointer and treat it exactly the same.

Comment: Too bad that you just deleted your question [How to implement cursor for text-editor in c++ with iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64831695/7478597). I just was about to post an answer. Though, I didn't use double-linked lists at all but followed the hint of Alan to use random access on a `std::string` instead...

Comment: Sorry i managed to solve it,  thank you for your effort, hope it was good practice for you, thanks again:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things you could do. You could declare it as a pointer

```
class Linkedlist { //Missing a c on your class declaration
    private:
        Node *head;
        Node *tail;
        int N;
        //Iterator point; (You have this declared twice)


    public:
        Iterator *point;
        Linkedlist();//s
```

In this case you'd need to call the constructor for point in the LinkedList constructor like so.

```
Linkedlist::Linkedlist() {
        N = 0;

        head = new Node();
        tail  = new Node();
        head->next = tail;
        tail->prev = head;
        point = new Iterator(head); // Use the existing constructor
}
```

Alternatively, you could create a default constructor for the Iterator class.

```
class Iterator {
           private:
               Node* iter;
           public:
               friend class Linkedlist;
               Iterator() {
                   iter = 0;
               }
               Iterator(Node* curr) {
                    iter=curr;
               } 
        };
```

Finally, you could use this syntax that instructs the program to allocate point with a null pointer before allocating memory for LinkedList.

```
Linkedlist::Linkedlist() : point(0) {
        N = 0;

        head = new Node();
        tail  = new Node();
        head->next = tail;
        tail->prev = head;
        point.iter=head;
}
```